# Bash shell logical Not with "!". What can't I see with this script?

Tags: bash

I use the following and it loops continually.  Why doesn't it stop when $i is below 10?

Thanks.

```
#! /bin/bash
#
        n=10
        nn=20
#
        for (( i=$(($n+$nn)) ; ! i<=10 ; i -=2 ))
        do
                echo $i
        sleep 1
                if [ $i -le 0 ]
        then
                 exit 99
        fi
        done
#
        echo "Done with the value of i which started at $(($n+$nn)) is exited with i=$i"
```

Answer (score 3):

You should simply use `>`:

```
for (( i=$(($n+$nn)) ; i > 10 ; i -=2 ))
```

Or try with parenthesis:

```
for (( i=$(($n+$nn)) ; !( i <= 10 ) ; i -=2 ))
```

Edited: I misread the doc (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html): *logical and bitwise negation* should work, but I suppose the `<=` has less priority than `!`.

Comment: ``(( i=$(($n+$nn))`` ugh, just `(( i = n + nn ...`

Comment: @KamilCuk Because Bash's enhanced `for` loop inherit the arithmetic context; so `$` could be omitted unless absolutely necessary: `for (( i = n + nn; 10 < i; i -= 2 ))`

Comment: I copy pasted the loop from the OP.... I do think that shellcheck display a warning about those.

Comment: Thanks all I’ve learned lots. That’s what all this is about. 

The response from Dan hits the original query I had and it is that I was negating just i and not the expression so my bad.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because `! i` is always less than ten. `!` does take precedence over comparison operators. The order of precedence for operators is listed in `man bash` > `ARITHMETIC EVALUATION`.

`! i <= 10` tests if the logical negation of `i` is less than or equal to ten. For all values of `i` except zero, where it's one, the logical negation of `i` is zero. So it will always be true.

Comment: Dan, excellent thanks. It is really clear now so good job.